# Do I need to exclude unprintable control characters from the pool of allowed characters in a pattern?

Tags: regex, xsd

I'm currently working on a xml schema, and we stumbled upon the wonderful world of whats included in BasicLatin and Latin1Supplement.

Until now, we mostly excluded `U+0009`, `U+000A` and `U+000D` (ie Horizontal Tab, Linefeed and Carriage Return). We're asking ourselves if we should bother excluding the rest of the control characters, ie. if there are any reprecussions if we do not exclude them.

The question thus is: should we exclude everything between `U+0000` and `U+001F` and `U+0080` and `U+00A0` as well as `U+007F` and `U+00AD`, or just dont bother and keep the three mentioned above?

Comment: Really do you need to?

Comment: There is no requirement, it came up in discussion and I thought I'd ask what others with maybe more experience think. My heart is not really in in either solution.